# How to build a division logic circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, calculator

I understand division in binary but applying it in a circuit is confusing. so far i have built adders/subtraction and multiplication circuits. i think i should have extra bits for radix bits. simple schematic that give me a kick about division logic circuit perhaps.

Comment: This is far too broad, just look at the options that Wikipedia offers about [Division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm)s. You can't implement a "simple" digital logic integer divider.

Comment: Division is normally done by a series of multiplications, with each output bit selected sequentially.

Comment: You should use a very small CPLD to do your division. Altera and Xilinx gives the primitives required for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Individual partial remainders must be derived from previously computed partial remainders in the chain. So it's more complicated.

This is only to give a kick, so to speak. I haven't checked it well. But I think it gets down an approach. It's combinatorial, though. Not sure if you want that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqMHsQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above is a 8-bit dividend (A) and a 4-bit divisor (B). (Well, if I didn't mess up in writing it out, which I may have.) There are lane changes taking place. If you look at a mux output you will see that the high order bit of the output is just dropped and the low order 3 bits are lane-changed to the upper three of a new bus, where its LSB comes from the next bit of A (dividend.) The A-side input of the next adder is then a composition, as described. Also, the top "mux" isn't really a mux. I just used that symbol for a comparator, instead. It's testing \$A[7:4] \ge B[3:0]\$, since if that part of A is larger or equal then the division will require a quotient larger than 4 bits. Hopefully, that's clearer.

Comment: The output of your 2:1 mux's are on the same wire as the inputs A.  This may be acceptable assuming you could cut off the A inputs, but, you can't in your scheme.  So the output of the 2:1 mux will be in constant contention with the A inputs. Or are those lines merging into 4:0?  I mean the A[1] joining with [3:0]->[4:1]

Comment: @jbord39: There are lane changes there. Do you not see them? I may need to edit that into something smaller!

Comment: @jbord39: Hopefully, that's clearer. I also may need to think about the details more. But the basic idea is to negate B (which is why the carry-in is always set to '1') and perform each stage as shown.

Comment: Quite an interpretive schematic.  You might want to label the nodes before and after each lane change.  For example the area which produces Q[2] (which is the CO of the previousAdder[3] if i understand correctly).  The CO of previousAdder[2:0] is used as the select for the 2to1Mux[2:0].  Maybe even just putting the # of parallel gates represented by each symbol would make it much clearer.

Comment: @jbord39: I wish I knew how to use this editor to make thicker bus lines, too. Then a thin line could be _seen_ as a single bit. Not sure. I will see if I can improve the diagram. Let me think a moment.

Comment: @jbord39: Well, I tried again. It's getting tedious to do much better. Hopefully, that gets things across (and/or makes any mistakes I made clearer.)