# Why does a divider needs 1 more step?

Tags: mips

My book introduces a divider design:

[image]

It said that if the divisor is n-length number, we need n+1 steps to finish the division.

For example: 7 / 2 (0111 / 0010) demands 5 steps. I don't quite get why it requires us to do 1 more step? It can automatically shift the divisor at the beginning.

This is the steps described closely:

[image]

Comment: I think one of the best ways to work out an answer to a question like this is to sit down with a piece of paper and perform the steps by hand. Doing so also forces you to have a firm, clear, intimate understanding of the logic, too.  Everything becomes so much clearer when you force yourself to do that and you'll have your answer in the context of your training, too. Just reduce this to a narrow bus -- maybe 4 bits as you show in your example?

Comment: Also, feel free to read this [non-restoring division discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389417/why-overflows-are-omitted-in-the-non-restoring-hardware-binary-division-algorith/391250#391250) and also this one on [division logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256665/how-to-build-a-division-logic-circuit/256672#256672). Either may help somewhat. But more likely the first one is closer and more detailed.

Comment: I have done them step by step and come up to this question

Comment: Can you write out the steps you are following in your question so that we can see each step and decide for ourselves how you handled each and arrived at this question?

Comment: Thanks for the addition. When I get a chance, I'll skim through them and see what comes from that.